# Variable needle pattern

Tags: php, replace

I would like to be able to replace a pattern that provides me with me the function arguments with the function's return.
I looked into `preg_replace` but I didn't find a proper tutorial for writing the `regex`.

#### Example:

```
    <?php
      function generate($content, $type, $id){
    
         $my_onthefly_content = 'Content is '.$content.', type is '.$type.', id is '.$id;

         return $my_onthefly_content;
      }
    
      $string = '
       <div>
         Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod.
           <p>
             {galery:events:30}
           </p>
         Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod.
       </div>';
    
    ?>
```

I want to output the string like this:

```
<div>
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod.
    <p>
      Content is galery, type is events, id is 30
    </p>
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod.
</div>
```

Comment: What's the `$string` for?

Comment: http://www.phpfreaks.com/tutorial/regular-expressions-part1---basic-syntax is a pretty good beginning tutorial.  You'll have to invest some effort if you want to understand regular expressions though, a lot of stuff won't hold your hand.

Comment: I want to output the given string with the brackets content replaced by the function return.

Comment: Depending on how complex of an application this is you may be better off using a PHP templating engine instead of trying to write one yourself with regex.

Comment: Isn't there a simple function that would do just that? I mean, I can take care of exploding the three variables. I only need to use what's inside the brackets as a single variable and replace the brackets content with the function result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With limited knowledge about what is *"valid"* for your `{::}` construct (you may want the limit the regex somewhat more the just "not `{` or `:` "), in any way you'd use [`preg_replace_callback()`](http://www.php.net/preg_replace_callback):

```
echo preg_replace_callback(
    '/\{([^}:]+):([^}:]+):([^}:]+)\}/',
    function($match){
         return generate($match[1],$match[2],$match[3]);
    },$string);
```

Comment: unexpected T_FUNCTION for function($match)  :(

Comment: @ValentinDragan: please upgrade your PHP version, PHP 5.3 has been around since 2009, and support will end in July next year. That being said, then your only current option is either define it as a named helper function, or use [create_function](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.create-function.php).

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following *regex*:

`\{(.*?):(.*?):(.*?)\}`

Explanation:

- `\{` : `{` needs to be escaped to match it
- `(.*?):(.*?):(.*?)` : match everything with : and capture it.
- `\}` : `}` needs to be escaped to match it

Unambiguous string examle:

`$string = ' Some Text
           {galery:events:30} Some Text
              ';`

Check if it matches your pattern:

```
if(preg_match_all("/$regexp/siU", $string, $matches)) {
  print_r($matches);
 }
```

Yes, it does!

### Working live example:

http://viper-7.com/EdNUFm

If you need more help and clarification, just let me know!